# alter database backup controlfile vs cp Linux file

Tags: oracle

We have the following explanation in the documentation:

> Back up the control file to a binary file (duplicate of existing
>   control file) using the following statement:
>
> ```
> ALTER DATABASE BACKUP CONTROLFILE TO '/oracle/backup/control.bkp';
> ```

My question is: why do I when modify control_files parameter to use the controlfile backed up with the alter database statement I need to do a recover the database and with cp command not? what is the difference between cp and the backup command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just move/rename control files (`cp`, `mv` ...) and modify accordingly `control_files` parameter - no need to do any recovery.

You may use cp only when instance is down or in nomount state. 
Otherwise, you can get inconsistent control file.
If we do:

```
  ALTER DATABASE BACKUP CONTROLFILE...
```

then we make "old", "not current" controlfile - backup controlfile.
With `cp` we make "current" copy of controlfile.

If we have current controlfile - no recovery is needed.
When controlfile is a backup controlfile then it requires recover and open resetlogs.

Here's a [link to documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96572/osrestore.htm#26488) -- old, but explains the concepts well.

Comment: Good edit, @mustaccio, thanks